# PHP find Value in multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

My Array looks like this:

```
$arr = Array();
$arr[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr[] = Array("test", "hello");
```

Now I want to check if `$arr`contains an Array which contains `foo` on first position.

Is there any function for this or should I just loop `$arr` and search through every Array inside it?

Comment: you might be able to use `array_walk` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), although that's a loop as well

Comment: I think there is no built in PHP function for this task, you may have to run a loop to achieve this.

Comment: If you want to check only in the first positions of the sub arrays then run a loop and search only in the first indexes.

Comment: You might be able to use a custom function and use PHP's built-in recursion with [`array_walk_recursive`](http://uk1.php.net/array_walk_recursive)

Answer (score 1):

One nifty little way of doing this would be to use `array_reduce` – by passing in a function that sums up the values 1 if `foo` was found, and 0 if not:

```
$foo_found = array_reduce(
  $arr,
  function ($num_of_hits, $item, $search_for = 'foo') {
    $num_of_hits += $item[0] === $search_for ? 1 : 0;
    return $num_of_hits;
  }
);

$xyz_found = array_reduce(
  $arr,
  function ($num_of_hits, $item, $search_for = 'xyz') {
    $num_of_hits += $item[0] === $search_for ? 1 : 0;
    return $num_of_hits;
  }
);

var_dump($foo_found, $xyz_found);
```

returns 1 and 0, cause `foo` is found once, and `xyz` is found zero times.

Answer (score 0):

Your Array:

```
$arr = Array();
$arr[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr[] = Array("foo", "hello");
```

My Solution:

```
echo search_in_array("foo",$arr); // This will show you the number of items found

function search_in_array($value, $arr){

  $num = 0;       
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ) {    
     if($arr[$i][0] == $value) {
            $num++; 
      } 
     $i++;
  }
  return $num ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few different ways to do it. please check the following

```
$arr_zero = Array();
$arr_zero[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr_zero[] = Array("test", "hello");
$arr_zero[] = Array("nal", "rob");
$array_one = array_shift(array_values($arr_zero));
$element = array_shift(array_values($array_one));
if($element=='foo');
echo "its ok";
```

or

```
$arr_zero = Array();
$arr_zero[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr_zero[] = Array("test", "hello");
$array_one = array_shift(array_values($arr_zero));
$element = reset($array_one);   // First Element's Value
if($element=='foo');
echo "its ok";
```

or

```
$arr_zero = Array();
$arr_zero[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr_one = $arr_zero[key($arr_zero)];
echo  $arr_one[key($arr_one)];
```

To get key

```
$arr_zero = Array();
$arr_zero[] = Array("foo", "bar");
$arr_zero[] = Array("test", "hello");
$array_one = array_shift(array_values($arr_zero));
echo  key($array_one);   // First Element's Key
```